# Do i have to recompile a .dll in order to use it on a Mono Android Project?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.android

I have recently acquired the student licence of [Mono Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) from Xamarin.

After making a simple project, i decided to start using some DLL's i am familiar with such as [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size.aspx) and [H.A.P](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/90925) on my Android Application (mono project), and that's when the problems started.

After trying to pull those references from NuGet, they failed since the "Android Application" project is not known leading to no .dll installed (NuGet tries to match the project type with the correct .dll to be downloaded be it WindowsPhone, .NET4, .NET 3.5 and so on).

So i moved on to mannually referencing the libraries, since i have them downloaded on my PC. Referencing Works, but as soon as i try to access the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/90925) it raises an exception.

```
Error CS0012: 
The type 'System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable' is defined in an assembly that is not     referenced. 
You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral
```

The exception is raised on the first execution of the code because of J.I.T compilation of .NET, i know this.

**Question:**
How can i use my "so loved" .dlls on my Mono Android Project?

Do i need the source code of those libraries in order to use them on my projects?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to recompile an assembly you will need the source.

To see what assemblies are provided by Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS you can visit these two pages:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/assemblies

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/assemblies

One way to recompile it would be to make a Android Class Library or iPhone Class Library and add a link to all the files in the original source and then compile it. Or when Xamarin have their PCL support done, do something similar just in a PCL so that you have one DLL targeting multiple platforms.

You may also find this post useful, which briefly describes how to compile HtmlAgilityPack against Xamarin.Android: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/2139/#Comment_2139 You might need to alter some things as this is from December 2012, since then things might have changed.

Comment: How do i recompile the source code against the assemblies provided by Xamarin ? Could you add it up to your answer please ? I bet it will help many others. Awesome Nickname by the way